# Trying to load a byte into DX, but the wrong value is getting loaded

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

I am trying to load the third value (03h) into DX, but the wrong value is getting loaded. I don't understand what's going on.

```
DATA SEGMENT
STRING1 DB 01h,02h,03h,04h

DATA ENDS 

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
START:
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS, AX
LEA BX, STRING1
INC BX
MOV DX, [BX+1]

HLT
CODE ENDS
END  START
```

OUTPUT:
The value DX is turning out to be 0403

[output screenshot from debug.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xjn3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to load the third value (03h) into DX,

Yes, but you're asking it to load 16-bit value, from address STRING+2 & STRING+3, so it loads 03 and 04, as 16-bit value in little endian: 0403.  `DX` is a 16-bit register, and by using it you're asking for a 16-bit transfer.

If you want just a single byte then use `DL`, for example, instead of `DX`

Otherwise, you can use `DW` in the data segment.  Data sizes and transfer sizes need to match.